# how to receive a json data from url in restlet for @GET in java?

Tags: java, json, url, get, restlet-2.0

Here is my code

```
public class JustinApplication extends Application {
  public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router();

    router.attach("/forresource/{id}", JustinResource.class);       
    return router;
  }
}
```

and am trying to send a JSon data through the URL

{"ID":"324"}.

I want to receive the json data in my resource class. I can get only as a string like this `%7B%22ID%22:%22324%22%7D` . But I NEED EXACTLY THE SAME DATA.
 How can I do this with the restlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get this `%7B%22ID%22:%22324%22%7D` because the value `{"ID":"324"}` got URL-Enecoded
when the request was sent.

you need to URL-Decode that and you will get your value.

```
String jsonParam = URLDecoder.decode(paramVal, "UTF8");
```

now you can use jsonParam, it will have `{"ID":"324"}`

have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to find out more